# How to programmatically stop editing QTreeWidget in Qt?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtreewidget, qt5.12

I have a `QTreeWidget` and two buttons "+" and "-". When I press "+" I want to add new item to QTreeWidget and I want that item to be in edit mode. I managed to do that with following code (it gets called every time "+" is pressed):

```
// QTreeWidgetItem* lastItem = getLastItem();
// if (lastItem) { widget->closePersistentEditor(lastItem); }

QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(widget, {"100000"});
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
widget->addTopLevelItem(item);
widget->editItem(item);
```

Problem is when I try to add a new item, but don't exit edit mode before adding (press Enter or something). I get error `edit: editing failed` and new item is added below current item (which is still in edit mode).

What I would like is that current item exists edit mode and that newly added item becomes focused and enters edit mode.

I tried to do that with first getting the last item in a `QTreeWidget` and calling `closePersistentEditor(lastItem)` (commented code) and then creating and adding new item, but it didn't work. So, how to close currently opened edit on item?

**EDIT**:
Ok, I have added additional code with minimal example. Only thing you have to do to build it is to add `QTreeWidget` and `QPushButton` to the form `mainwindow.ui` and connect that button to `on_btnAdd_clicked()`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget, {"100000"});
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
    ui->treeWidget->editItem(item);
}
```

**EDIT2**: This is happening on macOS (Mojave) with Qt 5.12.

Comment: `QTreeWidget` does not have a `getLastItem` method.

Comment: @user6528273, i suppose `getLastItem` is the OP-s own method. 
@dosvarog, can you share some more details about your code (maybe even a reproducible code snippet which demonstrates the issue)? Do you use a model  behind the view? And if yes, do you add the new item via the model?

Comment: @user6528273 Yes, that is my own method.

Comment: @zgyarmati What I have provided *is* minimal example. But I edited the question and added whole mainwindow.cpp. No, I use QTreeWidget, not QTreeView. No, I add new item as it is shown in the code.

Comment: What you have provided was _not_ a minimal, reproducible example, neither is the code you have added with the edit. For me it works as expected, i.e. each time I hit `Add`, a new item is added and an editor is open for it. If a previous item is being edited, its editor is resp. closed.

Comment: So you want me to provide the whole project? .h, .cpp, .ui, .pro and all other files? Those 4 lines in `on_btnAdd_clicked` are the most important and only 4 lines that do something. I guess our opinions on what is minimal example are not same. When I hit Add, new item is added, editor is opened, yes, that is true. But when I hit Add again (without closing editor), new item is added below first one, but first one is still being edited.

Comment: @user6528273 This is happening on macOS with Qt 5.12, it never hit me that on other OS-es behaviour can be normal. I just tried at home on Ubuntu, and it is working as intended

Comment: _this is happening on macOS with Qt 5.12_ see - without enough details, looking for a solution is like shooting in a dark room. Anyway, now it makes sense and I have retracted my close vote. So, it looks like either it was a bug, which has been already addressed, or a Mac specific issue. I am on Win 10 with Qt 5.15.1, so I can't help further.

Comment: It seems it is a bug in Qt, now I found some bug report with similar issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26838 . I didn't know that default behaviour is the one I am looking for, so it never occurred to me that it could be a bug. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This bug affects much older versions of Qt on windows 7. I suggest you to report it, stating the version and the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like this is a bug in Qt for macOS. Workaround that I did is following:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* lastItem = getLastTreeWidgetItem(widget);
if (lastItem) {
    widget->setDisabled(true);
    widget->setDisabled(false);
}
conversation->setFlags(conversation->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

`getLastTreeWidget()` is my own method that returns last added item in a `QTreeWidget`. Now every time when I press button to add new item, previous gets deselected and newly added enters edit mode.